# Two polynomials with complex coefficients whose level sets at $0$ and $1$ are the same

Tags: polynomials

For a polynomial  $f(X)\in \mathbb C[X]$, and $a\in \mathbb C$,  let $f^{-1} (a):=\{\mu \in \mathbb C : f(\mu)=a\}$.

Now let $f(X), g(X) \in \mathbb C[X]$ be non-constant polynomials such that $f^{-1}(0)=g^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}(1)=g^{-1}(1)$, then is it true that $f=g$ ?

Let $f^{-1}(0)=\{\mu_1,...,\mu_k\}; f^{-1}(1)=\{\gamma_1,...,\gamma_l\}$.

Then $f(X)=c_1\prod_{i=1}^k(X-\mu_i)^{n_i}, f(X)-1=c_1'\prod_{i=1}^l(X-\gamma_i)^{n_i'}$

$g(X)=c_2\prod_{i=1}^k(X-\mu_i)^{m_i}; g(X)-1=c_2'\prod_{i=1}^l(X-\gamma_i)^{m_i'}$

But I don't know how to proceed further.

Please help

Comment: A polynomial is determined by its zeroes, counted by multiplicity, along with one more constant factor.  Knowing $f^{-1}(0)$ determines the zeros, but not their multiplicity.

Comment: @JairTaylor but different multiplicities will tend to put the solutions of $f(x)=1$ at different points.

Comment: @Empy2 Ah, you are right.  I see now based on the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may assume without loss of generality that $\deg f\geq \deg g$.  Let $d=\deg f$, let $A=f^{-1}(0)=g^{-1}(0)$, and let $B=f^{-1}(1)=g^{-1}(1)$.  Note that $|A|=d-m$ where $m$ is the number of roots that $f'$ has in $A$ (counting multiplicity).  Similarly, $|B|=d-n$ where $n$ is the number of roots that $f'$ has in $B$.  Thus $$|A|+|B|=2d-(m+n)\geq 2d-(d-1)=d+1$$ (since $f'$ has $\deg f'=d-1$ roots in total).

But now notice that every point of $A\cup B$ is a root of $f-g$.  Since $f-g$ has degree at most $d$ and $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|\geq d+1$, this implies that $f-g=0$ and so $f=g$.

Comment: Beat me to it by 8 s! +1

Comment: Generalizing slightly, you've shown for any $c,d \in \mathbb{C}$ and $p \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ we have $|p^{-1}(c)| + |p^{-1}(d)| \geq 1 + \deg p$.  Very nice!